# Continuity of $f(x) = \|x\|$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, normed-spaces, epsilon-delta

> Show that $f(x) =  \|x\|$ is continuous.

I know that $f$ is continuous at $x'$ if $\forall\varepsilon >0$ there exists an $\delta$ such that $|f(x)-f(x')|< \varepsilon$.

So from here $|f(x)-f(x')| = \big| \|x\|- \|x'\|\big| \leq \|x-x'\|$.

However how do I find a good candidate for $\delta$ here since I cannot do a lot anymore with $||x-x'||$?

Comment: What are the domain and the co-domain of $f$?

Comment: Sorry for not stating. $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$

Comment: If $\|\ \|$ is a norm on a vector space, then $f(x)=\|x\|$ is Lipschitz, as you point out, so continuous.

Comment: I do not know if I understood the question, but if you take $\delta= \epsilon$ then for every $x$ such that $||x-x'||<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(x')|<\epsilon$.

Comment: @AnginaSeng: no offense to OP, but he's not going to know what a Lipschitz function is if he can't do an elementary delta-epsilon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $\delta=\varepsilon$. Then,$$\|x-x'\|<\delta\iff\|x-x'\|<\varepsilon\implies\bigl|\|x\|-\|x'\|\bigr|<\varepsilon,$$since$$\bigl|\|x\|-\|x'\|\bigr|\leqslant\|x-x'\|.$$